# Data truncated because data is longer than the target database column (IBM DB2)

Tags: sql, types, db2, varchar

I've been wanting to learn more about Data Analysis using IBM DB2 and SQL.
I want to upload a Covid-19 open source dataset to practice. However I'm getting this error: 'Rows truncated because the data is longer than the target database column' The database isn't loading ANY rows. Do I need to change the datatype? Right now it is specified as VARCHAR and DECIMALS.

Does anyone know the best way to handle this error?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Error: Data truncated because the data is longer than the target database column]

Comment: That error typically points to a conflict between the length (or precision) of data you are attempting to load and the datatype length (or precision) defined for the column in the database, with the incoming data having a greater length or precision than what can be inserted.
You should check the maximum precision (number of decimal digits) in your dataset, as well as the length of your string data, relative to the destination columns and adjust as appropriate

Comment: Yes you will need to change the table definition in the database. For VARCHAR the maximum length in bytes is 32,672 . For longer data, you need a different datatype like CLOB for example. Your question does not specify either the length of the target column, or the maximum length of the column that is in the dataset you are trying to use.   Learn how to ask a good question , by giving ALL information you have.